# Reproducing function from locally-integral moments

Tags: integration, polynomials, reference-request, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I am looking for a consistent theory (that is, something that is quotable, and that provides all relevant theorems) on the fact that a polynomial function can be reproduced by knowing its integration value on several independent domains. For instance it's clear that:

1. A $K^{th}$ degree 1D polynomial function $f(x)$ can be exactly reproduced by knowing its integrals $\displaystyle I_i = \int_{S_i\in \Omega}{f(x)dx}$ over a set $\Omega$ of $K+1$ (consecutive) segments.
2. A vector field of polynomial degree $K$ defined in a 2D domain can be reproduced by knowing its integrated divergence and curl over $K$ independent regions---In fact the integrated curl (resp. div) is enough to reproduce its coexact (resp. exact) components.

This sounds to me like some relatively basic property of finite-elements, or the method of moments, or just a variation on quadrature, but I couldn't find an exact reference uniting such properties.

Comment: Just to make it clear: it is easy to prove these properties for shear dof counting of linear equations. I just want to find out if there is an underlying theorem, rather than "invent the wheel".

Comment: Would you add a few words defining the term "independent regions". I am reading it as "disjoint regions", is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed disjoint regions.

Comment: I am intrigued by this question. I don't doubt that you have counted the number of unknowns and the number of equations correctly. I assume that it is the singularity or nonsingularity of the matrix that is the problem. This is what you are looking for?

Comment: They add up and it's easy to prove it works. What I am looking for is a unifying already-studied theory that demonstrates this, so I don't provide superfluous proofs for this property, and can just reference.

Comment: How does the second item work when the vector field is constant? Surely no information about this constant vector can be deduced from the divergence and curl which are both zero? By the way, curl is as far as I know only defined for 3 dimensional vector fields. What is your two dimensional version of curl?

Comment: Curl in 2D is the adjoint of rotated gradient. Or alternatively the divergence of the rotated (in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rads) field. Indeed divergence zero and curl zero imply a constant field. You are right though that it leaves 2 dofs, but that's the result of integration, so this is not entirely analogous to the polynomial example I gave in (1).

Comment: In (1) I reproduced a polynomial from its integral; in (2) I want to reproduce a field from the integral *of its derivatives*. That will inevitably be up to a constant dof.